# How to print something out and return another thing from a method in Java?

Tags: java, methods, printing, console

So I've got a method in Java that does some things with strings. At the end of the method, I do :

```
System.out.println(array[i-2]);
return(array[i-3]);
```

Basically, in this method I work with an array of strings. At the end of it, I have to print out one value, and return another value. Now I need to create a main method in which I will let the user input things as long as he doesn't input an empty row, then call this method, pass it that string , make the method do its work with the string and write out (print out) both of these values in the console (array[i-2] and array[i-3]). Lets say my method is named "StringFormating". How can I do this in main method? I've tried doing this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner();
String result="";
do{
 result=input.nextLine();
 }while(!result.isBlank());
```

and then doing something like `System.out.println(StringFormating(result));`

but it just gives me null references and I still don't understand how to actually print out both of those values in the console. Any help, please?

Comment: It's not easy to understand what your're asking. Could you write down the input that is given to the scanner and your expected output?

Comment: I am sorry. Basically, if input was "ABC,100,100\nABC,200,200" and I pass this input to my function and it decides that my result is this second row : ABC, 200,200 ; It will print out ABC and return 200 . I've done that. So now I need to do call this method in main and actually print out both ABC and 200 and I don't know how to do that

Comment: Because method is printing out ABC and returning 200. And I somehow need to make my main method so that when this string is passed to method, both of these "results" are printed out in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String result = "";
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter your string: ");
            result = input.nextLine();
            if (!result.isBlank()) {
                System.out.println(stringFormating(result));
            } else {
                System.out.println("Goodbye!");
            }
        } while (!result.isBlank());
    }

    static int stringFormating(String str) {
        String[] data = null;
        int n = 0;
        if (str != null) {
            data = str.split(",");
        }
        if (data.length == 2) {
            System.out.println(data[0]);
            try {
                n = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Error occured while processing data.");
            }
        }
        return n;
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter your string: abc,200
abc
200
Enter your string: xyz,40
xyz
40
Enter your string: 
Goodbye!
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to ask about Concatenation.  There are different ways to do this in Java it just depends on the source and use of the data.  The stringbuilder would work with this.  You can add new segments of data to the string builder and then print out its contents at the end.

Just a Note...  Taking data in from a user endlessly can be dangerous and throw overflow.
Of course no one will do this if your just doing a school project but in deploying products you need to make sure the user cannot break your code and this could cause a possible vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but this might be solution.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
while(!input.nextLine().isBlank()){
  sb.append(StringFormatting(input.nextLine()));
}
String result = sb.toString();
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your problem correctly, but it might be due to the do while. With a do while you always execute the body of the `do` before checking the condition in the `while`, so if you have an empty input you are going to save it in `result`. You might try doing this:

```
while(!input.nextLine().isBlank()){
    result = input.nextLine();
}
```

In addition to this, I would recommend you writing the name of the method with the first letter lowercase, this way `stringFormatting`, as it is a Java naming convention.